# How does a nested Kotlin coroutine scope work?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning Kotlin coroutines and I was trying to understand the coroutine scope. As per the Kotlin guide on [structured concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency),

> An outer scope cannot complete until all its children coroutines complete.

I created an example as below:

```
fun exampleCoroutine() {
        println("Corutine started")
        runBlocking {
            launch {
                delay(2000)
                launch { //child launch
                    println("nested child")
                }
                println("parent")
            }
            launch {
                delay(1000)
                println("in the second coroutine")
            }
            println("Hello")
        }
    }
```

And I get the below output

```
Corutine started
Hello
in the second coroutine
parent 
nested child
```

As per my understanding on how coroutine scopes work, I assumed that "nested child" would print before "parent". As that's clearly not the case, I want to know why "nested child" is printing after "parent".

And if my understanding is wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [`launch`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html):

> Launches a new coroutine without blocking the current thread and returns a reference to the coroutine as a [`Job`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/).

In other words, it launches a coroutine and returns immediately. The launched coroutine executes *asynchronously*. Note also that `launch` is *not* a `suspend` function.

---

You quoted:

> An outer scope cannot complete until all its children coroutines complete.

Looking at the following segment of your code:

```kotlin
launch { // parent launch
    delay(2000)
    launch { //child launch
        println("nested child")
    }
    println("parent")
}
```

That quote is saying the coroutine created by the "parent" `launch` cannot *complete* until the child coroutine created by the "child" `launch` *completes*. The last print statement in the block is not when the coroutine completes. A coroutine completes when the block *returns* and, as mentioned in the quote, all children coroutines have also completed.

You can see this better if you make use of [`invokeOnCompletion`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/invoke-on-completion.html) from the `Job` objects returned by `launch`. For example, the following:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    launch {
        delay(1000)
        launch {
            delay(1000)
            println("Child-1 end")
        }.invokeOnCompletion { println("Child-1 complete") }
        println("Parent-1 end")
    }.invokeOnCompletion { println("Parent-1 complete") }

    launch {
        delay(2000)
        println("Parent-2 end")
    }.invokeOnCompletion { println("Parent-2 complete") }
}
```

<sup>Kotlin Playground: https://pl.kotl.in/Oar099RZs</sup>

Outputs:

```
Parent-1 end
Parent-2 end
Parent-2 complete
Child-1 end
Child-1 complete
Parent-1 complete
```

Note that although the *last statement* of "Parent-1" is executed before "Child-1" completes, "Parent-1" does not *complete* until after "Child-1" completes.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot. I didn't realize the way "launch" worked and that clears up everything for me.